# Getting ComplementNB to run in Colab

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, google-colaboratory, naivebayes

I'm dealing with the classification of a severely unbalanced multiclass dataset. Luckily, the set is sufficiently large to forge ahead. I have been advised to consider using Complement Naïve Bays a la Rennie (http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf).

Using google Colab (is that where I went wrong?) I have given GaussianNB a spin without hitch, except that my precision is awful, when came to scoring time, of course.

However, I can't get the blasted CoplementNB to run.

Even though I

```
!pip install -U scikit-learn
```

as soon as I run

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import ComplementNB
```

I'm told that

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ComplementNB'
```

Followed by a suggestion to "manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt."

Any sages out there? 
Newbie here.

Comment: `ComplementNB` is released in scikit-learn 0.20, check what version you are running.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the pip above installs 0.20, and unistalls 0.19.  Is there something I should do in the "from sklearn..." line to ensure v0.20 is run?

Comment: Not really, [works fine out of the box](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rpQuE3BleIFcMY8xvi2ZMLoylN8G6sRg)

Comment: Solved, I think. Thanks @Alex Hristov. I snipped your code, pasted it in my worksheet and it still didn't work. but then I simply copied your workbook, and pasted my code below it, and it seems to work (I will still have to deal with negative values, I scaled the features, seems ComplementNB won't deal with negatives). I still don't know why it didn't work; perhaps it was the imports I made earlier ("from sklearn import preprocessing / from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, BernoulliNB). Either way, many thanks.